# Jelly's Untruth

Tags: code-golf, array, jelly

Jelly has an "untruth" atom: `Ṭ`. This takes a non-empty array of positive integers and returns a Boolean array with **1**s at the indexes in the input. For example:

```
[1,3,5,6]Ṭ ⁼ [1,0,1,0,1,1]
[5]Ṭ       ⁼ [0,0,0,0,1]
[2,1,1,2]Ṭ ⁼ [1,1]
[5,4,3]Ṭ   ⁼ [0,0,1,1,1]
[1]Ṭ       ⁼ [1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzjX/D7c/alpzdNLDnTP@/4821DHWMdUxi9VRiDYFEUY6hkBoBObrmOgYgxiGsQA)

Note that Jelly uses 1-indexing, and that duplicate values in the array have no effect.

Your job is to take a non-empty array of positive integers and output the result of applying `Ṭ` on the array. If your language has a builtin with this exact behaviour, you may not use it. You may also choose to use zero indexing if you wish (so the above examples become `[0,2,4,5], [4], [1,0,0,1]` etc) and take non-negative integers in the input array.

You may use your language’s `true` and `false` values instead of `1` and `0`, so long as they are the Boolean values rather than general truthy and falsey values (e.g. `0` and non-zero integers). You may also take input as a set if your language has that type. The input is not guaranteed to be sorted and may be in any order. The output may not have trailing zeros (or any other "trailing" values).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20559/66833). Imaginary brownies for beating my 9 byte Add++ answer (below), and extra imaginary brownies for beating (or tying) my 3 byte Jelly answer

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to be non-empty?

Comment: @xnor Yes, the input is guaranteed to be non-empty, and only contain positive integers that your language can handle (or non-negative if you choose zero indexing)

Comment: Are trailing zeroes permissible, or must it specifically match the output of `Ṭ` (rather than only fulfilling the requirement that it must contain 1s at the indices in the input)?

Comment: @UnrelatedString I’m going to say no, sorry, as I can’t think of a reasonable “limit” to the number of allowed trailing zeros beyond none

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I was hoping for a "no", but thought to ask because one approach that occurred to me would result in infinite trailing zeroes

Comment: Suggested testcase: `[5,4,3]` and `[0]`

Comment: @vrintle I’ve added the `[5,4,3]` test case, but given that I’m using 1-indexing in my examples, `[0]` doesn’t make sense. Do you mean `[1]` instead?

Comment: Oh, yes. I was using 0-indexing in my code :p

Comment: Isn't banning builtin's a bad idea?

Comment: @LiefdeWen Banning builtins is generally discouraged because it’s usually too vague to be objective. Stuff like “you may not use prime related builtins” for example. Here, I’ve banned this *exact* builtin to avoid trivialising the challenge (e.g. Jelly, 1 byte being an answer). Take a look at Bubbler’s answer to see how a similar builtin is used because *only* this *exact* builtin is banned

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the clarification

Comment: the function can be accepted not as a set, but as a list of unique values?

Comment: @a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae I’m going to say no on that one, as a set is inherently unique by definition, whereas a list can contain repeated values

Comment: The solution I'm working on in C uses a sentinel value to mark the end of the input and out arrays: is that allowed?

Comment: @ErikF E.g. a null byte? Yeah that’s fine, so long as the sentinel isn’t a possible input (positive/non-negative integer)

Comment: Can an output array be preallocated, or do we have to allocate it ourselves?

Comment: @EasyasPi Take a look at our [defaults for input/output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/66833). I’m presuming you’re talking about C, in which case I’m not familiar enough to make a proper judgement

Comment: The linked Q&A doesn't provide an answer to @EasyasPi's question, as far as I can see. I'd like to know the answer to the same thing. Yes, it is relevant specifically in C, but also in many other lower-level languages. I'd quite like to write an answer in assembly, but I don't know of a reasonable way of dealing with this type of dynamic memory allocation. It isn't a situation that an assembly programmer would get themselves into, and if they did, they certainly wouldn't return the memory buffer to another subroutine. They'd just allocate and use it directly on the stack.

Comment: @CodyGray Unfortunately I don’t know enough about memory allocation (read: I know nothing about memory allocation) to give a fair or informed answer. I’d recommend reading around meta for a consensus and if one doesn’t exist, opening a discussion

Comment: The other problem is that one cannot simply return a stack buffer in assembly without violating every calling convention on Earth, so there basically needs to be either a pointer to a buffer or a call to malloc/mmap.

Answer (score 13):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 3 bytes

```apl
×¯⍸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn///D0Q@sf9e74n/aobcKj3r5HXc2H1hs/apv4qG9qcJAzkAzx8Az@n6ZgqGCsYKpgxpWmYArERkC@oYIRAA)

A tacit function. Banning only the *exact* built-in actually gives APL a massive advantage!

#### How it works

```apl
×¯⍸
  ⍸  ⍝ Takes a vector v and gives another vector containing v[i] copies of i
     ⍝ for each index i
 ¯   ⍝ Inverse of the above, which counts occurrences of i which becomes v[i]
×    ⍝ Signum of each number, converting any positive count to 1
```

---

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
⊢∊⍨∘⍳⌈/
(⍳⌈/)∊⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HXokcdXY96VzzqmPGod/Ojng59Lg0oQxMk07Xof9qjtgmPevsedTUfWm/8qG3io76pwUHOQDLEwzP4f5qCoYKxgqmCGVeago4pkDACChgqGAEA)

Non-Extended solution. Works exactly like the [3-byte Jelly solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216740/78410).

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
∨⌿-↑⍤0×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HHikc9@3UftU181LvE4PD0/2mP2iY86u171NV8aL0xSLhvanCQM5AM8fAM/p@mYKhgrGCqYMaVpqBjCiSMgAKGCkYA)

A fun way to do the job. For each number `n`, create a length-`n` vector that has a 1 at the end and 0 for the rest. Then promote the entire array to a matrix (padding as necessary) and take the logical OR of the rows.

Comment: Leave it to bubbler to outgolf the builtin itself.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>42</s></sup> 41 bytes

*-1 thanks to @ovs*

```python
lambda a:[i+1in a for i in range(max(a))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcYxDoAgDADAr3QskcWoi4kvQYcaQZtAJQSNvr560@W3Hqd0GqZZI6V1I6DRcdOyAEE4CzD8LSS7x0QPkjGL5sJSMaC/KSJLviqan7rB9rZbPg)

Comment: Using 1-indexing is 1 byte shorter: https://tio.run/##DcYxDoAgDADAr3QskcWoi4kvQYcaQZtAJQSNvr560@W3Hqd0GqZZI6V1I6DRcdOyAEE4CzD8LSS7x0QPkjGL5sJSMaC/KSJLviqan7rB9rZbPg

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 11 bytes

```
{~l,1}ᵐz₁⌉ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/qv@6ip8eHWCYc2VZcrKejaKSiV2z9q2/Coqenhrs5aoMT/6rocHUMQqwqo8lFPJ0jsf3S0oY6xjqmOWaxOtCkQG@kYAqFRbCwA)

It's certainly interesting to consider what approach is the best in a language without a concept of a Boolean. 0-indexed. For some reason the unbound variables that are *pretty much* 0 are actually displaying as variables, so tack a `≜` onto the end if that's a problem.

```
{    }ᵐ        For each element of the input:
   ,1          append 1 to
 ~l            something that long.
       z₁      Ragged zip. (i.e. non-cycling, doesn't stop until all lists are exhausted)
         ⌉ᵐ    Take the maximum of each column.
```

Comment: I’m not sure I quite understand the output format?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing The numbers prefixed with underscores represent unbound, unnamed variables, which under most circumstances would appear to be 0, (including if you run [the same code as a full program](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v7ouR8ew9uHWCVWPmhof9XQCWf//R5vG/o8CAA)), but for some reason (I truly have no idea why) they're displaying this way with the test header. Adding `≜` would make them "really" 0.

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 20 bytes

```
SparseArray[#->1^#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P7ggsag41bGoKLEyWlnXzjBOOVbtf0BRZl4JiKtRZJvmoKypo6Rgq6Ck45NZXOLgUBSrVhecnJhXV81VbahjrGOqY1arw1VtCiKMdAyB0AjM1zHRMQYxDGu5av8DAA)

Returns a `SparseArray`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 30 bytes

```hs
f a=map(`elem`a)[1..maximum a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU7NisIwEL7nKeYgmMDYbfw7iNmbB2FPegwBpzS6YZtY2gpefZ99AcGX0Rfp9kcWcYZhYL6/@abyx2ZZXe@BlKec72xm/Y6EllHk6ez8yQOZ2pMLKj0y0JzQxcIsR7ywlJaLxaZZW70OlRHLwefBVl8uWAaZrSBRLScqQzoocwr8Qw31ULiYQV64UPEmEPbF0a/CyfPmA6FUgoSJYNAG1lriBGc4N/frLzwuN2gOMfYjDdOzDuirg2PsuwXHLQnHr9pOg1OcPHX/Gvk0lO@G0vwB)

The relevant function is `f`, which takes as input a list of integers `a` (1-indexed) and returns a list of `Bool`s.

Answer (score 5):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 5 bytes

```
Γ₁
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//8PcCQuAuOPc5EdNjR/mTp31/3@0oYKxgqmCWSwA)

Explanation:

```
        # Get Greatest element
        # Inclusive range: (0 .. n]
  Γ      # For each element in range do: 
   ₁     # 1st input line
        # Check that the int is in the list
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 35 bytes

```
[ 0 [ 2^ bitor ] reduce make-bits ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY29CoNAEIR7n2JeIKImlYG0wcZGUomBy2aD4s@ZvbMQ8dnNYhK2mBlm2O9lyFvZbkWWX1O0LAN3cOwdeuNrde@JB@JvDB@NFqOw9/MozeBhRMzscA6yPIUjMZ7qYAmABQmOOGHd/V9jRHrxL0Wq61aqlkju0OdWUEH4ORErsOXDDqx0c9lJCLUn24/WMdhQDerYyPYB)

Takes a sequence of 0-based indices and returns a virtual boolean sequence of `t` (true) and `f` (false).

#### How it works

```
[
  0 [ 2^ bitor ] reduce  ! Reduce all 2^n bitmasks by bitwise OR
                         ! for each n in the sequence
  make-bits  ! Create a virtual sequence of bits from the integer
]
```

Comment: Nice, it's not often to see this language "in the wild"

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby 2.7](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 33 bytes

```ruby
->a,n=[0]*a.max{a.map{n[_1]=1};n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ8822iBWK1EvN7GiGkQWVNdk1uRFZ8baGtZa59X@L1BIi4420DHSMdExjY3lAnNNYAxDHQMgNIRxTYGKjGEcg9jY/wA)

Uses the 0-indexing. TIO uses an older version of Ruby, whereas in Ruby 2.7, we've numbered parameters, which saves two bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 82 bytes

```java
a->{int m=0,r[];for(int i:a)m=i>m?i:m;r=new int[m];for(int i:a)r[i-1]=1;return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNboMwEIX3OcXIUiRoDQpp00UoqbrprqssEQuXQOQUGzQeUkURN@oFepyehJqfNKlSIWOP37z5xrMTe@HtNu@tVFWJBDsb@zXJwr8JJ1d3ea1TkqXuxLQQxsCrkBqOE4CqfitkCoYE2W1fyg0oqzlrQqm3cQICt8btUwFexjqPUlOc8P6/ghyiVnirow1BRTOOcRLmJTpdLJfCVZFcqSe5VCFGOvuAzqb@pmAsvSCJghAzqlEDhk0b9sieYdugzJCBaGwE4BjwO77gDw0/XSzOxzkP7De/0Pg9vzuHwXhsBobtBJy9wB6yHFDuL@kk2IlY/jOiOBifymFATqe4PmZVIdLMYcA4MObCLbDvr08WXtTAzNQF2RK5L6qqOAzW64z/OYN2TTr51wdDmfLLmvzKGih32NSbz7qRTc1U2@TxDfyMGc3NpFtN@wM)

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
v1i(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v8wwU@P//2hDHWMdUx2zWAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L/MMFPjv0vI/2hDHWMdUx2zWK5oUyA20jEEQiMQT8dExxhIG8YCAA).

#### Explanation

```
v   % Concatenate stack contents vertically. Gives an empty array
1   % Push 1
i   % Take input
(   % Assignment indexing: write 1 into the array at the input positions.
    % This automatically extends the array and fills with 0
    % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
Ṁe€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzobUR01r/h9uB5KR//9HG@oY65jqmMXqRJsCsZGOIRAaxQIA)

This does seem somewhat difficult to outdo.

```
  €    Map over (the range from 1 to)
Ṁ      the largest element of the input:
 e     is it in the input?
```

Silly, 0-indexed bonus:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
2*BUo/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99Iyyk0X///o4aZh9sfNa2J/P8/2lDHWMdUxyxWJ9oUiI10DIHQKBYA)

```
2*        For each element of the input, raise 2 to that power.
  B       Convert to binary
   U      and reverse each,
     /    then reduce by
    o     vectorizing logical OR.
```

Comment: Exactly the same as my 3-byter, nice!

Comment: I was thinking of Each-left, so I'm surprised simple Each works.

Comment: @Bubbler `€` is each-left (while `Ɱ` is each-right)

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
mo±€¹ḣ▲
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9odXNr//9tb8Kx4oKswrnhuKPilrL///9bMCwyLDQsNV0)

I feel like I'm missing a way to do this with `η`.

### Explanation

```
mo±€¹ḣ▲
     ḣ▲ range 1..max(input)
mo      map each to
   €¹   whether it's present in the input(index if present, 0 if not)
  ±     and take the sign of that
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>4</s> 3 bytes

```
ZLå
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/yufw0v//o410DIHQKBYA)

Yes it is just a port of every other answer.

### Explained

```
ZLå
ZL   # Push the range: [1, max(input)]
  å  # Vectorise: is item in input? over that range
```

Comment: The `€` is not necessary, `å` vectorises on its own.

Comment: I cannot understand `05AB1E`…

Comment: You aren't supposed to understand it. That is the magic of golfing languages.

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 49 bytes

```cs
a=>Enumerable.Range(1,a.Max()).Select(a.Contains)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY49C8IwFEX3/opHpwSegSh16cciCkpddHBOQyyB@gJNioL422NE0F250@UeDlf7mfY2bibSVWt9qCyFBmG7puliRtUNpuqcG5oGzgmBGqKqm@8oDop6wyQqsVc3xrk4msHowJRYOQrKkuexzLJUvEv4abTBtJYM82G01Iuds8RyzPGlZ2Su8HnBONxBIiwQCoQlPDjn5e@m4l@BxHmKfGviEw)

Saved 3 bytes thanks to caird

Saved 1 byte thanks to didymus

Saved 2 bytes thanks to NonlinearFruit

Comment: You can save three bytes by removing the `?1:0` and changing `int` to `bool`

Comment: Hmm, didn't think about the output format, thanks

Comment: You can save a byte using `Contains`: `a=>new bool[a.Max()].Select((x,i)=>a.Contains(i+1))`

Comment: Save 2 bytes: `a=>Enumerable.Range(1,a.Max()).Select(a.Contains)`

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 12 bytes

```
e.~1 i.@+>./
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZBCkBAGEDhvVO8LJgJP4OxMJFSVlauIMLGDVx9TK@v3uNjSU@GnpScij4ohHlbF3/IZ7hlykYpvY6Ijv16Ue7UiYwoQ4Olc1hHjQnV4WlpHEb7Hw)

0-indexed; similar to Bubbler's APL solution

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

-2  bytes thanks to coltim

```
{~^x?!1+|/x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qui6uwl7RULtGv6L2f5q6hqGCsYKpgpm1ho6pprWRgiEQGlmbKpgoGAOFDDU1/wMA)

0-indexed

Comment: Would be nice here if `I.inv` were implemented.

Comment: @xash Yes, it would be nice

Comment: Can [trim a byte](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qOjMvWtFQu0a/Irai9n@auoahgrGCqYKZtYaOqaa1kYIhEBpZmyqYKBgDhQw1Nf8DAA) from the oK answer by using `in`, i.e. `{in[!1+|/x]x}`

Comment: Scratch that, can [save two](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qui6uwl7RULtGv6L2f5q6hqGCsYKpgpm1ho6pprWRgiEQGlmbKpgoGAOFDDU1/wMA) with `{~^x?!1+|/x}`

Answer (score 3):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), <strike>60</strike> 58 bytes

```
func t[S](n:S):S=
 for i in 1..n.max:result.add int i in n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/rTQvWaEkOjhWI88qWNMq2JZLIS2/SCFTITNPwVBPL08vN7HCqii1uDSnRC8xJQUoXAKRzPufmpyRr@AQbaijYKyjYKqjYBarV8IFFTRFYhvpKBiCkRGyAh0FE6BGJBFDIPs/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>32</s> <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```r
function(x)1:max(x)%in%x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQtPQKjexAkirZuapVvxP00jWMNQx1jHVMdPU5ErTMAURyRpGOoZAaKQJ4ZnqmOgYg9mGmv8B)

Taking advantage of `%in%` operator and abusing weird precedence.

*-1 thanks to [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)*

#### 21 bytes using `scan`

```r
1:max(x<-scan())%in%x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/39AqN7FCo8JGtzg5MU9DU1M1M0@14r@hgrGCqYLZfwA)

Comment: Nice.  I think you've left a spurious space in there, though...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen You're right!

Comment: @Someone I've rejected your suggested edit as site policy is to [suggest golfs in comments, rather than directly edit them in](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1619/66833)

Comment: Very clever, and simple! Before looking I would have implemented something like @DominicvanEssen's answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 19 bytes

```scala
i=>1 to i.max map i
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MgwzKES7QeG56E8pB0d5qg)

Returns a `Seq` of `Boolean`s. Takes a `Set[Int]` as input, since sets are also predicates in Scala. If a list is taken as input, `i.contains` would have to be used instead.

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 17 bytes

```matlab
@(x){y(x)=1,y}{2}
```

Anonymous function that takes a row (or column) vector as input and produces a row vector as output.

Uses the last trick on [this list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104753/36398) to effectively include several statements in an anonymous function.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0KzuhJI2BrqVNZWG9X@T9OINlQwVjBVMIvV5AJyTCGUkYIhEBpBxRRMFIwhTMNYzf8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 45 bytes

1-indexed, which felt weird to do in a 0-indexed language. Accepts only non-negative integers; negative indexing in powershell is 1-based, so this answer breaks down for negative cases.

```powershell
$a=,0*($args|sort)[-1];$args|%{$a[$_-1]=1};$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVBNT4NAEL3zKyabrYBdTKl6qSFprFVPPaiJB0IapGMlpYC7S6qh/HZcQFpMQ5w97Hy8ffP2pckOufjAKCrpexYHMkxiRwMVeUl9h43ODerztdiLhEvTtWzvpqkHOfVdulQNxy5Uryw0KlHImS9QgANTo2aZ5vVVRRinmaySamizMbs2DzP8SjGQuKpnxAYbRurYpEEUrJeml@Lfp2N2ya76nqvd1WlJNLP7uT0MIK/rRbZ9Q64MaHbQegED2iGjy4umq5K23YA5iiySCnJ2cB6mNbaZiywIUFRekl8sAQs/VdXykBr4ykOJ1mMiJBD3RamCjjYPCJyGtUgWuIvCGE8ZqGHo934YZRx1pj83InTTbfV4pke6DGDd@sFmzZMsXs2SKOGgCO58vnnClSKosgeOGP@hOFk7geMf@8UpbQTceevuwQiPMFdIHsZrbzKZb1P53V1GoDH06MpwqBXlDw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>25</s> 21 bytes

```julia
x->1:max(x...).∈[x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5NCoNADIX3OUWQLkZIxdG2i4JexM5C6gyMWCs6hTmC@0JXPZ0XsY4/4KIJWSTve4@Ur0rn3I4KExztMeXXR26ZDYLAD4a@z6wYjexMN8kZZJxiOtNFYJLitIS0DBcE2VngUk4LaelZiRxC0eZaaDpRLHY033L4PsddBACoZ4tMU@mjrnF@CMAxSk@PKab9edNqPiRYwpqBTatrU9XMG75v9Ai1i1UrL6tO/iM/O5LQuxkmbSPvRhZ4KH1vNdcFTDP@AA)

Comment: Were these Unicode operators removed from Julia later? I don't see them much anymore.

Comment: no, they are still there, and I personnally use them a lot. Although in code golf they are not the best since they are 3 bytes (but here `in` doesn't work)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>24</s> 23 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to pajonk*

```r
F[scan()]=1;F&!is.na(F)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/3y26ODkxT0Mz1tbQ2k1NMbNYLy9Rw03zv7GCmYL5fwA)

A different approach to [pajonk's R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216763/95126).
Shorter at time of posting, but this is a precarious situation, as it would be longer in a fair 'apples-with-apples' comparison (using `scan()` for both approaches).

Comment: -1 byte: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/3y26ODkxT0Mz1tbQ2k1NMbNYLy9Rw03zv7GCmYL5fwA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @pajonk - Really nice!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>45</s> 44 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(b=>c[b]=1,c=[])&&[...c].map(d=>d|0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY4xDoMwDEX3niITSiQ3xJSOzkWiDCGBqhUlCKpOvXtKYQAhalte/P/zf7i3G/1w71/nLoY6NZQcaSefrucVaW8qSwiejBVZZqSU3s63QDp8lEg@dmNsa9nGG2@4UVBACVcrBMtzZhgCU7BuZPa0c5Q/7VKzQ8E6B3IENTVuHxxB4QLFAt5A8V8GtcswSdIX)

This implementation uses zero indexing and returns an array of `0`s and `1`s.

I think the code isn't very difficult to understand. Here's a summary explanation:

- `c=[]`: create the output array.
- `a.map(b=>c[b]=1     )`: for each value of the input array, set 1 at the respective index in the output array.
- `[...c].map(d=>d|0)`: convert the output array into a non-sparse array, then map each element to a 32-bit integer. This will map `1` to `1` and `undefined` to `0`.

Thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602) for -1 byte.

Comment: Wait, one does not simply outgolf @Arnauld... although having said that there is a byte going spare: `a=>a.map(b=>c[b]=1,c=[])&&[...c].map(d=>d|0)`.

Answer (score 3):

### x86_64 (zero indexed, length given), <strike>19</strike> 16 bytes

Raw machine code:

```
31 c0 57 f3 aa 5f 89 d1 8d c6 04 07 01 e2 f9 c3
```

Uncommented assembly:

```asm
        .intel_syntax noprefix
        .globl untruth
untruth:
        xor     eax, eax
        push    rdi
        rep stosb byte ptr [rdi]
        pop     rdi
        mov     ecx, edx
.Lloop:
        lodsd   dword ptr [rsi]
        mov     byte ptr [rdi + rax], 1
        loop    .Lloop
.Lend:
        ret
```

#### Explanation

I'm not too good at x86, so I am pretty sure there is a better way to do this.

C signature:

```c
// System V ABI (rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx)
void untruth(bool *out, const uint32_t *indices, uint32_t indices_len, uint32_t out_len);
```

It's my function, I can order the parameters however I please.

First: `memset(out, 0, out_len)` using `rep stosb`. Since we need to save the pointer and `stosb` clobbers it, we `push` and `pop` it.

The standard calling conventions say that the direction flag is always cleared when calling, so we know this will be a forwards operation.

```asm
untruth:
        xor     eax, eax
        push    rdi
        rep stosb byte ptr [rdi]
        pop     rdi
```

Using the fancy `loop` instruction, loop through each index in the array, storing 1 to `out[index]`

```asm
        mov     ecx, edx
.Lloop:
        lodsd   dword ptr [rsi]
        mov     byte ptr [rdi + rax], 1
        loop    .Lloop
```

At the end of the loop, return.

```asm
.Lend:
        ret
```

Note: It also happens to be x86-compatible on the binary level.

Thanks to Neil for the -3 bytes (using lodsd)!

### x86_64 (zero indexed, calculates max), 28 bytes

Raw machine code:

```
31 c0 57 51 af 0f 42 47 fc e2 f9 91 56 56 5f f3
aa 5f 59 5e ad c6 04 07 01 e2 f9 c3
```

Assembly:

```asm
        .intel_syntax noprefix
        .globl untruth
        # void untruth(const uint32_t *indices{rdi}, char *out{rsi}, uint32_t indices_len{rcx})
untruth:
        xor     eax, eax
        push    rdi
        push    rcx
.Lfind_max:
        scasd   eax, dword ptr [rdi]
        cmovb   eax, dword ptr [rdi - 4]
        loop    .Lfind_max
.Lfind_max.end:
        xchg    ecx, eax
        push    rsi
        push    rsi
        pop     rdi
        rep stos byte ptr [rdi], al
        pop     rdi
        pop     rcx
        pop     rsi
.Lloop:
        lodsd   eax, dword ptr [rsi]
        mov     byte ptr [rdi + rax], 1
        loop    .Lloop
.Lloop_end:
        ret
```

This version will check for the maximum itself, *but the output buffer provided must be large enough.*

Probably many things here can be optimized.

### Explanation

Note that the parameters are different than the first: `indices` is in `rdi`, `out` is in `rsi`, `rdx` is unused, and `indices_len` is in `rcx`.

I don't know why `scasd` uses `rdi` but whatever.

This is a simple max loop. It compares each dword in `indices`, and sets `eax` to the maximum.

This seems to be smaller than doing something with `lodsd`, although that 4 byte `cmovb` is pretty yucky.

```asm
untruth:
        xor     eax, eax
        push    rdi
        push    rcx
.Lfind_max:
        scasd   eax, dword ptr [rdi]
        cmovb   eax, dword ptr [rdi - 4]
        loop    .Lfind_max
```

Since we know `ecx` will be zero due to the loop condition, we can set `ecx` to the maximum *and* set `eax` to zero in one byte.

```asm
.Lfind_max.end:
        xchg    ecx, eax
```

Unfortunately, our output array is in `rsi`, not `rdi`. We `push` and `pop` twice to mov without the `REX` tax and save a copy, then do a `memset` with `rep stosb`.

```asm
        push    rsi
        push    rsi
        pop     rdi
        rep stos byte ptr [rdi], al
        pop     rdi
```

Now we need to get `indices` and `indices_len` from the stack. Note that this time, we put `indices` into `rsi`.

```asm
        pop     rcx
        pop     rsi
```

For each dword in indices, `out[indices[i]]` to 1 using `lodsd` and `loop`

```asm
.Lloop:
        lodsd   eax, dword ptr [rsi]
        mov     byte ptr [rdi + rax], 1
        loop    .Lloop
```

Return.

```asm
.Lloop_end:
        ret
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! My x86 is a little rusty but maybe you can use lodsd to read the source array?

Comment: Thanks! I forgot `lodsd` used `rsi` instead of `rdi` lol

Comment: I was thinking about an assembly solution myself, but wasn't happy with anything that I could come up with. This submission has a similar problem: how do you know how long to make the output array? It seems that you don't; you're relying on the caller to specify that length, but that is, at least to me, a very fundamental part of the challenge.

Comment: Counterargument: Then we should disqualify all of the languages with automatically resizing and zeroed arrays. There is none of that in assembly, although I could technically write a version which does that.

Comment: I'm confused, shouldn't `scas+cmova+loop` find the max in the array, or am I reading the docs wrong? [Try it online!](https://bit.ly/34Kt472)

Comment: Nevermind, I'm dumb. I had the conditions reversed. ‍♂️

Answer (score 3):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 4 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
>0⍘⊚
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAgPjDijZjiipoKCmYgWzAgMiA0IDVdCmYgWzRdCmYgWzEgMCAwIDFdCmYgWzQgMyAyXQpmIFswXQo=)

0-indexed

```
>0⍘⊚
  ⍘⊚  # inverse where (occurrences)
>0    # where is it greater than zero?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 9 bytes

```
L,dbMR$€e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HJyXJN0jlUdOa1P8qOYm5SSmJCoZ20YYKxgqmCmaxXP5cXEjCpugCRgqGQGgEFP4PAA)

Given that no-one besides me really uses Add++, I figured I wouldn't be sniping anyone

### How it works

```
L,dbMR$€e - Anonymous lambda function
L,        - Define the lambda function. Takes l as input
  d       - Duplicate; STACK = [l l]
  bM      - Maximum;   STACK = [l max(l)]
  R       - Range;     STACK = [l [1 2 ... max(l)]]
  $       - Swap;      STACK = [[1 2 ... max(l)] l]
  €       - Over each:
    e     -   In l?
```

Comment: Did you manage to post this 0 seconds after posting the question?!

Comment: @xnor I ticked the "answer my own question" box when writing up the question :P

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), `-pa` 33 bytes

```perl
@r[@F]=(1)x@F;map$_+=0,@r;$_="@r"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9@hKNrBLdZWw1CzwsHNOjexQCVe29ZAx6HIWiXeVsmhSOn/f0MFAyA0/JdfUJKZn1f8X9fXVM/A0OC/bmJBDgA)

`0` indexed.  Input and output are space separated.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r5Jm@7@4NKk6t9KhyNqhKNohPtZWw1CzwiEeyKv9b60Sb5uVn5mnoqSTm1igEl9joKOSpmun4eCmqfDfUMEACA3/5ReUZObnFf/X9TXVMzA0@K@bWJADAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online") could save some bytes using sub

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul I don't think the `undef` elements in the returned list satisfy the question requirements. The question says one and zero or true and false are okay, but not general truthy and falsy categories. Which put my similar answer at 35 bytes: `sub{my@r;@r[@_]=(1)x@_;map{0+$_}@r}`

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r5Jm@7@4NKk6t9KhyNqhKNohPtZWw1CzwiHeOjexQCW@xkDHoaj2v7VKvG1WfmaeipKOSpqunYaDm6bCf0MFAyA0/JdfUJKZn1f8X9fXVM/A0OC/bmJBDgA "Perl 5 – Try It Online") @aschepler, Ok i didn't readotherwise 34 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 44 bytes

```sh
for i ({1..${${(nO)@}[1]}})<<<$[$@[(I)$i]>0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIVNBo9pQT0@lWqVaI89f06E22jC2tlbTxsZGJVrFIVrDU1MlM9bOIPb///@G/43/m/43AwA)

Explanation:

```sh
             ${(nO)@}                          # sort the arguments numerically, in reverse
           ${        [1]}                      # take the first (i.e. maximum value)
       {1..              }                     # range from 1 to that
for i (                   )                    # for each i
                                @[(I)$i]       # find the index of `i` in `argv`, or 0 if not present
                              $[        >0]    # is that positive? (1 or 0)
                           <<<                 # print
```

Comment: Happy to see another Zsh answer! [I used a completely different method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216799/86147)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 50 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(g=(x,i)=>x&&g(--x,g,o[x]|=++i/i),o=[])&&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1BDoIwEEX3noJV04YpUBB35SJNFw1CU4MMAWO68O7VpjFGZSaz@Mmb9y/mbrZ@dcuNz3gewiiDkZ0prmahVlIPjsnOE2Ip5x4soPL6IfPclY4BSqUZIRh6nDechmJCS0eqBDTQwkkzlpVl9ooVpBP68IO2EUoT0QrS/oN1fIf649xxwRGa5Hu7xG6p@C4VOjwB)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                // a[] = input array
  a.map(            // for each ...
    g = (x, i) =>   // ... value x at position i in a[]:
      x &&          //   if x is not equal to 0:
        g(          //     do a recursive call:
          --x,      //       decrement x
          g,        //       force i to a non-numeric value
          o[x] |=   //       update o[x]:
            ++i / i //         set it to 1 if i is numeric (≥ 0)
                    //         or just coerce it to a number otherwise
                    //         (i.e. undefined values are turned into 0's)
        ),          //     end of recursive call
      o = []        //   start with o[] = empty array
  ) && o            // end of map(); return o[]
```

Comment: I should learn a new language so I don't keep getting beat to these ...

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
rÔõ!øU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ctT1IfhV&footer=bSsw&input=WzEsMyw1LDZdCi1R)

```
ÍÌÆøXÄ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=zczG%2bFjE&footer=bSsw&input=WzEsMyw1LDZdCi1R)

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 25 bytes

```sh
for x;a[x]=1
<<<${a/#%/0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P9w5xoNTY3/aflFChXWidEVsbaGXDY2NirVifrKqvoGtf81ubiAahQMFYwVTBXMwGxTMGkEFDNUMIKIKJgoGEPU/QcA)

The `#` and `%` in globs act like the regex `^` and `$` anchors, but for full words instead of lines.

Altenatively, `<<<${a:///0}` works.

---

[Very similar Zsh solution to another question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194813/86147)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) with `-m32`, 87 bytes

Zero-indexed, using `-1` as a sentinel value for arrays.

To get the size of the output array, I recursively scan the input array and allocate the output array with the maximum size found (plus one for the sentinel.) After that, each input index is marked and the resulting array is returned.

```c
*j;*g(i,m)int*i;{~*i?g(i+1,m<*i?*i:m)[*i]=1:(j=calloc(++m+1,4))[m]--;i=j;}f(i){g(i,0);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVHLboMwELzzFRuqSLYxFSS0hzgkPxD11hPlQHkkG/GogLQHRD691AaaNCqt5MPuzHrG3gnNfRh2HTsKtifIM4p5zVA0Z4ZbCRg2z9ayZLjKqMfQd@0VObphkKZFSAwjkwMOpV7mm6ZA9yjahCBtlJRFRdvdYR6mpyiGdVVHWNwfNtoNlOKrwjTpCmmc7@sDUSULypJCowGoDoUmq6QoCbqWgLMkPfQFoGFQIZkyrk9lrsbaQSkLMCfvBUZXDaXo@a5qAZSH59PG5rDk8MDhkYNpt/yGtDgsODg9/4ucwpwJTCrY/VlMkBK2@mNPOzj986Z8ln8KTn3jgj0973Z90XJgLBDf@5VdGVentL4sOnDlvoTcmoCkjGMy0HTY548scD2mxgI6BAJvpdRMiO7No3mlG7OZlFe0jIzfzJv2Vuegr3Qf3A3ofZQqTOXkJnJijHfKbnzPP5bDxK3peOtq/JIPtq3Wdp9hkgb7qjM/OjNbLr4A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>52</s> 49 bytes

```hs
t=foldl(#)[]
l#i=take i(l++[0,0..])++1:drop(i+1)l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBCoMwEEX3nmLATUJGSazdiDlCTxCGEtDSwVGDzbJ3T9PF5/EW77/jZ1tFSsn@dcoiqtWBGmnZ57itwEqMCRZt35M2xk3LdSbFxmkpe@QDPOwxPZ6QLj4yhAzylbkLNRlwxDthGOsc1gt0f8MbDpWWiJryAw)

- 0 indexed

Answer (score 2):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 7 bytes

```
e:⌉┅¤Ė¦
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/P9XqUU/noymth5YcmXZo2f//0cYKJgpmCmaxAA)

Identical to, e.g., [pajonk's R answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216763/67312)

```
e:		# eval implicit input as a list and duplicate
⌉┅		# take the max of the list and compute [1...M]
¤		# swap so [1..M] is on the bottom
Ė¦		# For each element of [1..M], is it in the input list?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), <s>30</s> <s>29</s> 27 bytes

```
range(max)as$a|[$a+1]-.==[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/78oMS89VSM3sUIzsVglsSZaJVHbMFZXz9Y2Ovb//2hDHWMdUx2zWAA)

### Explanation

```
range(                      # the 0-range up to
  max)                      # the largest item of the input - 1
as$a                        # And assign it to $a

|                           # And then, for every item in $a:
[$a+1]-.==[]                #     Is the item + 1 contained in the original input?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
Gɾƛ?$c
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=G%C9%BE%C6%9B%3F%24c&inputs=%5B6%2C3%2C5%2C1%2C3%5D&header=&footer=)

```
Gɾƛ?$c
G      Maximum
 ɾ     Range
  ƛ    Map:
   ?     Push the input
    $    Swap
     c   Contains?
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=G%C9%BEvc&inputs=%5B6%2C3%2C5%2C1%2C3%5D&header=&footer=) for 4 bytes

Comment: @lyxal Is there a documentation on command line flags somewhere? I was actually wondering why something like that doesn't work (without the flag)…

Comment: [Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=h&code=&inputs=&header=&footer=) for a list of flags

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 38 bytes

```
f(l)=[0^{(k-l)^2}.maxfork=[1...l.max]]
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jjwxjs2je7)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 5 bytes

```
Đ↑ř⇹∈
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yIRHbROPznzUvvNRR8f//9FGOoZAaBQLAA)

```
Đ          implicit input; Đuplicate
 ↑         get maximum
  ř        řangify
   ⇹∈      is each element in [1,2,...,max] in the input?; implicit print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
GRƇ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPW1heCUyMHJhbmdlJTIwY29udGFpbnMmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0lNUIxJTJDMyUyQzUlMkM2JTVEJmZsYWdzPXY=)

##### Explanation

```python
GRƇ  # Implicit input
G    # Maximum
 R   # Range
  Ƈ  # Contains
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Go 1.21+](https://go.dev), 112 bytes

```go
import."slices"
func f(I[]int)(o[]int){
for i:=1;i<=Max(I);i++{e:=0
if Contains(I,i){e=1}
o=append(o,e)}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVHNSgMxEMajeYpxoZDgWLqtFWmNINpDD4pobyqyrImEtsm6m5XKkifxUgTBV_BR9GnMZi3VJoTMzzfzTb68vj2a5WeWpNPkUcA8UZqoeWZy247k3EbvpZV7h1_ZKlbMVCqKiMhSpyDp-OZOacuoae6KSJODGvB4qI74ebKgYzZUu7uVGPAOURJOjbaeoqBjVKwSPHbE8CTLhH6gBgVzJBe2zLVreL-3PuxLJmAChc3L1EJFtpXOEMQig0BJHGlmqSenzAOsKGwBA-7zk4pUAVXF2MM-HjhcuR1sTuwcrkB9hxBW43aw2X8h3boEu-s-_-pxH3t1j3V9vEER_6cIKUcuc-_MNI0453A9ObmagLciFtS8R1u_Jk-0_5_mcV6FJA1RSW3bC8K8LBLMtA6Nnspk5sNeIgQPY0PY8ZkKAoukUev5Vtcj8GOoTboyGbTsrY4QQstQW9uhj5kycJuTwujiDH4n_f2w5bK5fwA)

Uses the new `slices.Max` function from the standard library, which doesn't exist pre-1.21.

Answer (score 2):

## [Noulith](https://github.com/betaveros/noulith), 33 bytes

```perl
\l->for(x<-1to(max l))yield x in l
```

Uses 1-indexing.

[Try it online!](https://betaveros.github.io/noulith/#Zjo9ClxsLT5mb3IoeDwtMXRvKG1heCBsKSl5aWVsZCB4IGluIGwKOwoKc3RydWN0IFQgKGlucCwgd2FudCk7Cgp0cyA6PSBbClQoWzEsMyw1LDZdLFsxLDAsMSwwLDEsMV0pLApUKFs1XSxbMCwwLDAsMCwxXSksClQoWzIsMSwxLDJdLFsxLDFdKSwKVChbNSw0LDNdLFswLDAsMSwxLDFdKSwKVChbMV0sWzFdKV07Cgpmb3IgKHQgPC0gdHMpICgKYSA6PSBmKHQuaW5wKTsKcHJpbnQodC5pbnAsIGEsIHQud2FudCwgYT09dC53YW50KTsKKQ==)

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, 13 bytes

```
seq(max(I=Ans),I,1,max(Ans
```

Takes input in `Ans`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 51 bytes

```
.+
$*01
+`^((.)*).?(.*)¶(?<-2>.)*(?(2)$)(.+)
$1$4$3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcgxDoAgDADAve@oSQu1gYKbkUe4GxwcXByMb/MBfgzJbXcfz3ntbaC1SlMP6EIEXzciZcdaSB1/L5V5tKUPFTJGJvUMGDFjai2ISZYJMkQJXYQsSQzCDw) Takes input as a newline-separated list but link includes test suite that converts from comma-separated for ease of use. Outputs a binary string. 0-indexed. Explanation:

```
.+
$*01
```

Convert each entry into a string of `0`s followed by a `1`.

```
+`
```

For each additional entry, its `1` is merged into the first line in turn:

```
^((.)*)
```

Match the prefix on the first line.

```
.?(.*)¶
```

Skip the digit above the `1`, if any, but keep the suffix of the first line.

```
(?<-2>.)*(?(2)$)
```

Match a prefix of the same length on the second line.

```
(.+)
```

Match the any `0`s needed for padding and the `1`.

```
$1$4$3
```

If the first line was shorter than the second line, then append the suffix of the second line to the first line, otherwise insert the `1` from the second line in between the prefix and suffix of the first line.

Example 1: When merging `10001` with `001`, the prefix is two characters, `10` (captured as `$1`) on the first line corresponding to `00` on the second line. The `1` (captured as `$4`) from the second line is then inserted, and then the suffix `01` on the first line (captured as `$3`) is appended, resulting in `10101`.

Example 2: When merging `101` with `00001`, the prefix is three characters `101` (captured as `$1`) on the first line corresponding to `000` on the second line. The `01` (captured as `$4`) from the second line is then appended (`$3` is empty as the first line is shorter than the second), again resulting in `10101`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
⭆⊕⌈θ∧№θι¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaHjmJRel5qbmlaSmaPgmVmTmluZqFGpq6ig45qVoOOeXAhUX6ihkAgUMNTU1rf//j4420DHSMdExjY39r1uWAwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a binary string. 0-indexed. Explanation:

```
   θ        Input array
  ⌈         Maximum
 ⊕          Incremented
⭆           Map over implicit range and join.
     №      Count of
       ι    Current index
      θ     In input array
    ∧       Logical Or
        ¹   Literal `1`
            Implicitly print
```

1-indexed version is also 9 bytes:

```
⭆⌈θ∧№θ⊕ι¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaPgmVmTmluZqFGrqKDjmpWg455cC5Qt1FDzzkotSc1PzSlJTNDI1gbKGmpqa1v//R0cb6hjrmOqYxcb@1y3LAQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Same as the first version, except that the increment is in a different place.

Answer (score 1):

## FALSE, 183 bytes

```
0$$b:c:d:[^$1_=~][$32=$[%%0a:[a;b;=~][a;1\[$0=~][\10*\1-]#%*a;0=~[+]?a;1+$b;=~[@\]?a:]#0b:c;1+c:$d;>[$d:]?1_]?~[b;1+b:48-]?]#%[b;d;>~][0$e:[$1=~e;c;=~&][e;1+$e:øb;=[%1]?]#.32,b;1+b:]#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY4xDsIwDEWvEqkOQ6EobouEHJVwD8dUSRsmNvaei52DFUds/s/fT36m17vsuwPItNBK/ACcp00Yhn4CttYl4uSzryx5jAyujhFdG7GTxrbJK@GjBF0foTb5HjWRNE6lCheC1d8YVpKAs4SNs9JM47WToAqNulerg0IMOG3FL@o5CJfqLPT9qJct1vp56E//e2n0c9Ob0VzMDw)

NOTE: Since FALSE does not actually have arrays, input is space-separated numbers with one space at the end, and output is the same.

Most of this answer is just input string to int.

0 indexed.

Answer (score 1):

## [HBL](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl), 9.5 [bytes](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
'?(*(*-,.
*().(0(/.
```

1-indexed. [Try it here!](https://dloscutoff.github.io/hbl/?f=0&p=Jz8oKigqLSwuCiooKS4oMCgvLg__&a=KDEgMyA1IDYp)

#### Explanation

The helper function on the first line takes two arguments: a list of indices and a specific index. It returns 1 if the index appears in the list, 0 if it does not.

```
'?(*(*-,.
    (*   )   For each element of
        .    the list,
      -      subtract it from
       ,     the index
  (*      )  Take the product of the resulting list
'?           Is the product zero?
```

The main function takes a list of indices and returns the "untruthed" list of 0's and 1's:

```
*().(0(/.
    (0    )  Range from 1 to
      (/ )   the maximum of
        .    the list
*            For each element,
 ()          call the helper function
   .         with the index list as first argument
             and the element of the range as second argument
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 29 bytes

```arturo
$->a->map 0..max a'x->a<>a--x
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?it5TsF)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 33 bytes

```powershell
1..($a=$args|sort)[-1]|%{$_-in$a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZJdb4IwFIbv@RUnTZ0Siwlu7sKExMy57cqLbckuCDEMj46IwNqSbVF@OysginEO26Rf5/Q5b980jr6Qiw8MgowuktCTfhRaGqi2ycxer0Ndi7p8KbYi4lK3DdPZtjZ0ZvghddMs1ahEIceuQAEWjDrFzdGmmPLmh3Ei80UeNFmfDfR9DL9j9CTOixihkicIu3HhBuIw5WekvJeys/B/wY3X@@ya3ZxF1ITUx0bqoIn453ShYFP1/gV2Nlun3j5gtw2oIw9ODKmKaHr9S2yhBZtiP03W78gtMy010EIAA1orRWe98lQtquMymaNIAqlSrvZ/dEco4yLxPBT5DyS7XAIGfqpdxSFF4hv3JRpPkZBA7FelCmraHCBw2oxpNMWvwA/xlEA7nfaD6wcJxzZrv5Qi2rpd6XF0h9QJYNy53mrJoyScj6Mg4qAA9y5fPeNcAfLVI0cMjxAnZYdweON5cUobAXtSubs3wiHMFpL74dIZDifrWP7UixEoDT240u1qafYL)

Takes in an array of positive integer, returns an array of booleans.

I stole the test cases from [Zaelin's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216773/97729), thank you!

### Explanation

```powershell
1..($a=$args|sort)[-1]            # Generate a range from 1 to the maximum number in the input
                      |%{$_-in$a} # If the number is in the input list, returns $true, otherwise $false
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), <del>94</del> 83 bytes

Saved 11 bytes thanks to @att

Golfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVHdSsMwFMbbPUW6C0kkK3Q_ItYNfAbBGyklZCkEsrQmpzpo9yTe9ELfwQfxRp_GtNnq1O4EcnJyvp9w8vJqSgvNe6bRhkmNCapGyIUSgDK0RG8lZJOrz7uaXd8LfpOu6snKHyocheHygoUShMEk3LCt20v9bFiBSVsXuJY1C3muwUlbfC7dNc-VEhww2Xnpr7OPuHcEYSHlzArrrJ8EDx66Vhu4KyM6owt6mVDfBVMKijKmrEsDRbsnhP4RWRzoe-xgGqZOaeTW9Lf_CRc6p7Nhpx_aKXJ07HBoJ_Goy1luEJa6KIEisS3cNMU6zUtwFwRJfTzFqtdtx-sxbrSZp5O4bzNrhYFUPAbYo_5Le_DOv6EwUoPSAR7fKtU5WlS0Iutg7JD7z20an78B)

```rust
|a:Vec<_>|->Vec<_>{(1..=*a.iter().max().unwrap()).map(|i|a.contains(&i)).collect()}
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVJLTsMwEJVY5hSTLpANbkRaihCFSFyCDaoiN3WQJdcJ_pSKNidh0wVcitPg2CkUSG3Jo5l5b95oPG_vymqz231YUw6vP0-eSgklojfwwIpbq_kryzAMM-_Oq0pksInAHcEMLOk6X1EBd3BGE26YQjhxMfda-aJojfDUY9FFknTYFlCjLd8CTYpKGsqlRqeIn6cYYxcRghUG4aiJItfI0qURPlA0TJu8oJppJ7piRfzoU17EuykZkwm5mpGQNcoyAiUV2pkep31nmPwpMtnTO2yv6aeOSOru6Lf-ERVyScb9Sj-0Y-T0UGGfnk0jb8tKAeKytoYAW9duomyRV9a4AAYuD6e4-a7bjjdg3GjLQO_-rz1Ua6ZMzp5jFFD_SwdwE3qoFZdGyBgN7oXwihrqtsgiHjhkE_atW7v9-n0B)

```rust
fn f(a: Vec<usize>) -> Vec<bool> {
    let max_val = *a.iter().max().unwrap();
    (0..max_val).map(|i| a.contains(&(i+1))).collect()
}
```

Comment: [83](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVHdSsMwFMbbPUW6C0kkK3Q_ItYNfAbBGyklZCkEsrQmpzpo9yTe9ELfwQfxRp_GtNnq1O4EcnJyvp9w8vJqSgvNe6bRhkmNCapGyIUSgDK0RG8lZJOrz7uaXd8LfpOu6snKHyocheHygoUShMEk3LCt20v9bFiBSVsXuJY1C3muwUlbfC7dNc-VEhww2Xnpr7OPuHcEYSHlzArrrJ8EDx66Vhu4KyM6owt6mVDfBVMKijKmrEsDRbsnhP4RWRzoe-xgGqZOaeTW9Lf_CRc6p7Nhpx_aKXJ07HBoJ_Goy1luEJa6KIEisS3cNMU6zUtwFwRJfTzFqtdtx-sxbrSZp5O4bzNrhYFUPAbYo_5Le_DOv6EwUoPSAR7fKtU5WlS0Iutg7JD7z20an78B)